# Equal widths of subviews with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos

I'm trying to build a simple watchOS UI with SwiftUI with two pieces of information side-by-side above a button.

I'd like each side (represented as a `VStack` within an `HStack`) to take up half of the available width (so it's an even 50/50 split within the yellow parent view) divided where the *|* character is centered on the button in the example below.

I want the *Short* and *Longer!!!* text to each be centered within each side's 50%.

I started with this code, to get the elements in place and show the bounds of some of the different stacks:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            
            VStack {
                Text("Short").font(.body)
            }
                .background(Color.green)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Longer!!!").font(.body)
            }
                .background(Color.blue)

        }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Button (action: doSomething) {
            Text("|")
        }
    }
}
```

Which gave me this result:
[image: starting point]

Then, when it comes to making each side-by-side `VStack` 50% of the available width, I'm stuck. I thought it should work to add `.relativeWidth(0.5)` to each `VStack`, which should, as I understand it, make each `VStack` half the width of its parent view (the `HStack`, with the yellow background):

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            
            VStack {
                Text("Short").font(.body)
            }
                .relativeWidth(0.5)
                .background(Color.green)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Longer!!!").font(.body)
            }
                .relativeWidth(0.5)
                .background(Color.blue)

        }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Button (action: doSomething) {
            Text("|")
        }
    }
}
```

But this is the result I get:
[image: unexpected widths]

How can I get the behavior I want with SwiftUI?

---

**Update:** After reviewing the SwiftUI documentation more, I see [the example here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/securefield/3289408-relativewidth) that sets a frame and then defines a relative width in comparison to that frame, so maybe I'm not supposed to use `relativeWidth` in this way?

I'm a step closer to what I want with the following code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            
            VStack {
                Text("Short").font(.body)
            }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)
            
            VStack {
                Text("Longer!!!").font(.body)
            }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)

        }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Button (action: doSomething) {
            Text("|")
        }
    }
}
```

which produces the following result:

[image: closer to expected result]

Now, I am trying to figure out what's creating that extra space in the middle between the two `VStack`s. So far, experimenting with getting rid of padding and ignoring safe areas does not seem to affect it.

Comment: The yellow area is the HStack's default spacing (you can override it by specifying explicitly `HStack(spacing: 0) { .. }`)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I'm still confused about when and how `relativeWidth` is supposed to be used, but I was able to achieve want I wanted without using it. (**EDIT 18 July 2019:** According to the iOS 13 Beta 4 release notes, `relativeWidth` is now deprecated)

In the last update to my question I had some extra spacing between the two sides, and realized that was the default spacing coming in on the `HStack` and I was able to remove that by setting its spacing to 0. Here's the final code and result:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {

            VStack {
                Text("Short").font(.body)
            }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)

            VStack {
                Text("Longer!!!").font(.body)
            }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)

        }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Button (action: doSomething) {
            Text("|")
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the result:
[image: final result without spacing]

Comment: With this setup, you don't need to wrap each `Text` in a `VStack`. The frame takes care of the layout you want (as long as the texts fit in half the view's width)

Comment: You don't even need to wrap the wrapping `VStack`. Calling `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` for the children is sufficient.

Comment: I think this only works/looks good on a watch because it will divide all the available space equally to the buttons. On iPad this would look quite strange (but the question was specifically for watchOS)

Answer (score 9):

Here's how to create an **EqualWidthHStack** for **watchOS 9, iOS 16, tvOS 16 & macOS 13**

[image: Equal width texts]

Here's the usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private let strings = ["Hello,", "very very very big", "world!"]

    var body: some View {

        EqualWidthHStack {

            ForEach(strings, id: \.self) { string in

                ZStack {

                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                        .opacity(0.2)

                    Text(string)
                        .padding(10)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

First create a `struct` that conforms to `Layout`.

```
struct EqualWidthHStack: Layout {
    ...
}
```

It will come with two default methods, here's how you can implement them.

Size that Fits:

```
func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
    
    let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
    let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
    let totalSpacing = spacing.reduce(0.0, +)
    
    return CGSize(width: maxSize.width * CGFloat(subviews.count) + totalSpacing,
                  height: maxSize.height)
}
```

Place Subviews:

```
func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
    
    let maxSize = maxSize(subviews: subviews)
    let spacing = spacing(subviews: subviews)
    
    let sizeProposal = ProposedViewSize(width: maxSize.width,
                                        height: maxSize.height)
    
    var x = bounds.minX + maxSize.width / 2
    
    for index in subviews.indices {
        subviews[index].place(at: CGPoint(x: x, y: bounds.midY),
                              anchor: .center,
                              proposal: sizeProposal)
        x += maxSize.width + spacing[index]
    }
}
```

You will need the following two helper methods.

Max Size:

```
private func maxSize(subviews: Subviews) -> CGSize {

    let subviewSizes = subviews.map { $0.sizeThatFits(.unspecified) }

    let maxSize: CGSize = subviewSizes.reduce(.zero, { result, size in
        CGSize(width: max(result.width, size.width),
               height: max(result.height, size.height))
    })

    return maxSize
}
```

Spacing:

```
private func spacing(subviews: Subviews) -> [CGFloat] {

    subviews.indices.map { index in

        guard index < subviews.count - 1 else { return 0.0 }

        return subviews[index].spacing.distance(to: subviews[index + 1].spacing, 
                                                along: .horizontal)
    }
}
```

Here's Apples WWDC22 video on how to make it:

[Compose custom layouts with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc22/10056)

Comment: @gohnjanotis I know this is not exactly what you are after as this will be more compact rather than full width, but I hope it can help others.

Answer (score 4):

There is very simple solution:

```
HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
    ForEach(0...6, id: \.self) { _ in
        Color(UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.4))
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .padding(2)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    }
}
.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
.frame(height: 70)
```

and the result is the following:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have set `background` of `HStack` to yellow color and `HStack` has some default inter child views spacing. By adding `spacing: 0` in `HStack` will solve the problem see the updated code below.

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack(spacing: 0) { // Set spacing here
            VStack {
                Text("Short").font(.body)
            }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.green)

            VStack {
                Text("Longer!!!").font(.body)
            }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.blue)

        }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.yellow)
        Button (action: doSomething) {
            Text("|")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it,

```
struct CenteredItemHStack: View {
   var body: some View {
       ZStack {
           HStack {
               Text("Leading Action")
                   .background(Color.blue)
               Spacer()
           }
           Text("Center Action")
               .background(Color.red)
           HStack {
               Spacer()
               Text("Trailing Action")
                   .background(Color.blue)
           }
       }
       .background(Color.green)
   }
}
```

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYEnW.png)